# Can not include "linux/in6.h" without errors on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ipv6, ipv4

I can not include the `linux/in6.h` header into my source code without getting these redefinition errors:

```
In file included from mypmtud.cc:30:0: /usr/include/linux/in6.h:30:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct in6_addr’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0,
             from mypmtud.cc:23: /usr/include/netinet/in.h:198:8: error: previous definition of ‘struct in6_addr’ In file included from mypmtud.cc:30:0: /usr/include/linux/in6.h:46:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct sockaddr_in6’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0,
             from mypmtud.cc:23: /usr/include/netinet/in.h:239:8: error: previous definition of ‘struct sockaddr_in6’ In file included from mypmtud.cc:30:0: /usr/include/linux/in6.h:54:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct ipv6_mreq’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0,
             from mypmtud.cc:23: /usr/include/netinet/in.h:275:8: error: previous definition of ‘struct ipv6_mreq’ make: *** [mypmtud] Error 1
```

How can I include the `linux/in6.h` file into my code? I need `linux/in6.h` for `IPV6_DONTFRAG` definition and `setsockopt()` to understand this option. 
All other header files i have included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

#include <sstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <map>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on VirtualBox 4.2.6.

Comment: I might be reading the error output wrong, but it seems like `in.h` includes `in6.h` for you. In that case, shouldn't you already have `IPV6_DONTFRAG` available? Generally, you shouldn't really need to include the system-specific headers. (Unless that option is non-standard.)

Comment: probably providing the actual `gcc` command that you have used for this can be a good idea ...

Comment: @millimoose: `IPV6_DONTFRAG` is not defined in `in.h`. I can define it with `#ifndef IPV6_DONTFRAG #define IPV6_DONTFRAG 62 #endif` but I'm not sure if that's a good solution. @user1849534: `g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -g -pedantic -W -DDEBUG -lresolv`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `linux/in6.h` has name conflicts with `netdb.h`. If you can discover that all the names you need from `netdb.h` are in `linux/in6.h` you can remove that and you should be fine. Also, reading it once more makes me think it might already be included in `netinet/in.h` for you.

**Edit**:

(From a comment below:)
Let me break down the error message for you then: `/usr/include/linux/in6.h:30:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct in6_addr’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0` i.e. 'struct in6_addr' was already defined in netdb.h. Next `netinet/in.h` also provides that struct which causes another conflict. And everything after that is about there being a struct previously defined in both `netinet/in6.h` and netdb.h while trying to include `netinet/in.h`. Are the sections of code that use `netdb.h` and `linux/in6.h` separate? If so, try different files. I think with different files any conflicts you may have will be removed since each file is sort of a namespace (I'm thinking of namespaces in the context of python). I'm not 100% certain of this, but I'm going to check later.

Comment: I can not delete `netdb.h` because it contains more definitions and functions than `linux/in6.h`. Without defining `IPV6_DONTFRAG` myself or including `linux/in6.h` I get `IPV6_NOTFRAG not defined in this scope`.

Comment: Let me break down the error message for you then: `/usr/include/linux/in6.h:30:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct in6_addr’ In file included from /usr/include/netdb.h:28:0` i.e. 'struct in6_addr' was already defined in `netdb.h`. Next `netinet/in.h` also provides that struct which causes another conflict. And everything after that is about there being a struct previously defined in both `netinet/in6.h` and `netdb.h` while trying to include `netinet/in.h`. Are the sections of code that use `netdb` and `linux/in6` separate? If so, try different files. I'll edit my comment with more.